# Using hook_form_alter(), how do I write a multi-select field?

Tags: 6, forms

So I have a field that displays locations a list of multi-select locations.

The select has a name of `field_location`

I want to turn access to this off, and then rebuild the field with a limited list of  locations that I will populate.

```
function rm_report_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state){
    if (arg(0) == 'node' && $form['form_id']['#value'] == 'c_node_form') {
        $form['field_location']['#access'] = FALSE;
    }   
}
```

The problem:  Not sure how to rewrite a multi-select field.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are searching for the #multiple attribute:

## multiple

Used by: select

Description: Indicates whether the user may select more than one item.

Values: TRUE or FALSE

```
<?php
return array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => $title,
  '#default_value' => $value,
  '#options' => $options,
  '#description' => $description,
  '#multiple' => $multiple,
  '#size' => $multiple ? min(12, count($options)) : 0,
  '#weight' => -15,
);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you try to accomplish. However the code should look more like this:

```
function myModule_form_formID_alter(&$form, &$form_state){
    if (arg(0) == 'node') {
        $form['formID']['field_location']['nid']['nid']['#access'] = FALSE;
    }
}
```

You can use the [devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) and its [dpm()](http://api.lullabot.com/dpm) statement, or even more powerful get [Xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/) running on your dev machine to see the full structure of the data.